# textbox inside updatepanel losing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

I have an **updatePanel** that has a **textbox** as a *content* and a **dropdownlist** as a *trigger*.
whenever i change the the *selectedIndex* of the **dropdownlist**, it will query the database, and it will get me a *value* for the **textbox**.

now i entered some new *value*, and click the *Update* **Button** so it will be saved in the database.

the problem here, it keeps getting me the old *value* (the value that been brought by the **dropdownlist**).

how i can solve this?

EDIT

```
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplKmAllowed" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtKmAllowed" runat="server" Width="215px" OnTextChanged="txtKmAllowed_TextChanged">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind: this is to add trigger programatically becase the cboAsset is in a usercontrol

```
   asset = fltrAsset.FindControl("cboAsset") as ASPxComboBox;
asset.AutoPostBack = true;

asset.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Asset_SelectIndexChanged); 
        AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
        trigger.ControlID = asset.UniqueID;
        trigger.EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged";

        uplKmAllowed.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

the function

```
 protected void Asset_SelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tudID = asset.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
        RentalTracking rtk = new RentalTracking();
        string assetID = rtk.getAssetIDDepartmentIDbyTudID(tudID)[1];
        RentalAssetInfo rai = new RentalAssetInfo();
        rai.GetRentalAssetInfo(Int32.Parse(assetID));
        if (rai.KMAllowed == 0 || rai.KMAllowed == -1 || rai.KMAllowed == null)
        {
            kmallowedSaved = false;
            txtKmAllowed.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            txtKmAllowed.Text = rai.KMAllowed.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the **IsPostback ??** if yes can we see you code please

Comment: yupzz, the code has a IsPostback, in the pageload,

Comment: Does the textbox have runat=server in it?

Comment: yes, the textbox has a runat=server in it, and i have tried to make the button autopostback=false, so it wont refresh until it get the value, but its not working as well :S

Comment: Is the UpdatePanel inside of the UserControl?

Comment: nope, the updatepanel is in the aspx, but its trigger in side the usercontrol

Comment: You've got a couple problems: 1) By default, UpdatePanels have their UpdateMode set to "Always", so unless you put `UpdateMode="Conditional"`, your UpdatePanel will post back every time. 2) The way you are rigging your button to be the "trigger" really isn't doing what you think it is. You are really just circumventing the UpdatePanel altogether.

Comment: Depending on what your ScriptManager is called, you would do: `ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(cboAsset);`

Comment: @scott actually, when i select any thing from the dropdownlist, it give the values to the textbox without refreshing, this means the trigger is working fine, i got the problem when i change the value in the textbox, and click update, the value that stores in the db , is the value that brought at first place, not the one i updated.

Comment: @msytNadeem Right, it's working, but not through the UpdatePanel mechanism. I bet if you removed the UpdatePanel, it would still work.  Based on your code, I don't see where you are setting the `cboAsset` as the trigger for the UpdatePanel. `cboAsset` is outside the UpdatePanel, right?

Comment: look at the code, its in the part2, i created a new AsyncPostBackTrigger and i choosed the cboasset, and i assigned it to the updatepanel

Answer (score -1):

```
use asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger in update panel
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplKmAllowed" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtKmAllowed" runat="server" Width="215px" OnTextChanged="txtKmAllowed_TextChanged">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LnkEditBuyingLead" EventName="EventName"/>
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```